# Javascript Firefox Extension - div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

How can I make a Firefox extension to click a div which is only defined by a class not an id. Like for example:

```
<div class="testBtn">Click me</div>
```

The site supports jQuery so in the firefox console it is possible to write: `$(".testBtn").click()`

But if I put the same code segment into my js file, it's not working. How can I get this to work?

The site that is supposed to be clicked is not my site, so I can't modify it.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share with us? Or can you set up a fiddle to demonstrate the issue you're having?

Comment: To setup fiddle wouldn't work because it is an extension for the browser and not really a website. And the source code is just a basic extension with a button to execute a function and this is working because I can open an alert box with the button.

Comment: If this is the only thing you're adding, Greasemonkey could be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `trigger` instead.

```
$(".testBtn").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it a little and now it's working. `$(".testBtn", MyMainWindow.content.document).trigger("click");`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use $ from firefox addon. you have to use document.querySelector to get the first hit, or document.querySelectorAll.

so `document.querySelector('.testBtn')` will return the first element with class testBtn

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelectorAll

also you can use use querySelector on elements. like:

`document.querySelector('.testBtn').querySelectorAll('div')` will get you all the divs in first testBtn classed element

but the equivalent of that with one line is probably `document.querySelectorAll('.testBtn > div');` or maybe without the `>`

then on your elements obtained from the querySelector's you just add a .click()

now from firefox-addons you're probably going to use `gBrowser.contentDocument` in place of `document`